# How to print a date with a custom format in Java 8?

Tags: java, string, date, printf

I'd like to create a formatted chart as the one displayed below:

[image]

The character count in each of the fields is 4, 12, 17, 40 and 4 respectively. The fields are also left-justified.

By using the code that I posted below, my result looks like this:

[image]

Code snippet for formatting:

```
for (Tasks examined : shortList) {
  String yesNo = examined.isDone() == true ? "yes" : "no";
  System.out.printf("%1$-4s" + "| " + "%2$tY.%<tm.%<-12td." 
     + "| " + "%3$-17s" + "| " + "%4$-40s" + "| " + yesNo + "\n"
               , examined.getNumber(), examined.getDeadline()
               , importanceLevel, examined.getName())
}
```

The variable types are:

```
examined.getNumber() //integer
examined.getDeadline() //DateTime
importanceLevel //String
examined.getName() //String
```

I've studied the Formatter class in the JavaDocs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). But I have couldn't solve the problem.

The main issue here, is the dot (**.**) at the end of the 'date' field. It shouldn't have all that whitespace between the date and the full-stop.

I wanted to organize the width of the 'date' element, with the -12 flag, but that just cut the rest as the final dot above.

How could this be solved?

Comment: Can you show how these variables look before being formatted ? :`examined.getNumber(), examined.getDeadline(), importanceLevel, examined.getName()`

Comment: Sure. In order: normal number e.g. 1, the date stores in DateTime format: 2018 and 12 and 12, the next is a String and the last one also.

Comment: Please consider choosing my answer as the accepted solution, if it has helped solve your question. You can do that by clicking on the **check mark** next to the answer. You can check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on how to do it. Kösz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might solve your problem, if I understood your requirements correctly:

```
int index = 1;
                                   //yyyy, MM, dd, hh, min
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 12, 31, 12, 10);
                               //specify custom pattern here
String date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd.").format(ldt);
String importance = "kozepesen fontos";
String name = "egyik feladat";
String yesNo = "yes";
String formatter = "%-4d| %-12s| %-17s| %-40s| %-5s%n";
//now use System.out.format() to print with pattern specified in 'formatter'
System.out.format(formatter, index, date, importance, name, yesNo);
```

Output:

`1   | 2018.12.31. | kozepesen fontos | egyik feladat            |   yes`

1. In the solution above, we inevitably convert the date to a string. That is, so we can specify a *custom* pattern for displaying the date. First we create a `DateTimeFormatter()` instance, with the desired pattern. The pattern is specified with the DateTimeFormatter's `ofPattern(String pattern)` method. Then, to get a String as the return type, we use the `format(TemporalAccessor temporal)` method from DateTimeFormatter again. We can use the DateTime instance as the `TemporalAccessor` parameter in `format()`, just as shown in the code above.
2. So how does `String formatter = "%-4d| %-12s| %-17s| %-40s| %5s%n"` work?
   I used the syntax for the [Formatter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for Java 8.

   `-` -> *The result will be left justified*.

   `%` -> *The result is a literal*.

   `n` -> *The result is the platform-specific line separator*.

   `d` -> *The result is formatted as a decimal integer*.

   `s` -> *If the argument arg is `null`, then the result is "null". If arg `implements Formattable`, then `arg.formatTo()` is invoked. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking `arg.toString()`*.

Lastly, the numbers I used, specify the amount of characters to allow for each field.

3. Then finally, we call `System.out.format` instead of `printf()`, where the *format-specifying string* is the **first** parameter and all the other variables to format must be typed **in the correct order** (the same order as the one in the *format-specifying string*).

Comment: Perfectly working. Very elegant solution. What I missed was the line separator and the formatter. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!